# Option to create a header for grouped content with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have tabled content with a specific vendor which I want to apply to the group of content that it applies to. See an extract of the content in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <story>
        <text>
            <table>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000W7LM</td>
                    <td>Diversified Growth A</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>108.26</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>1.51</td>
                    <td>114.66</td>
                    <td>88.29</td>
                    <td>108.74</td>
                    <td>1st Fusion Asset Management</td>
                    <td>011 731 5290</td>
                    <td>1.44</td>
                    <td>2019-12-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P00016K7H</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000VCZN</td>
                    <td>Guarded A</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>112.65</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>3.06</td>
                    <td>113.26</td>
                    <td>100.86</td>
                    <td>112.46</td>
                    <td>1st Fusion Asset Management</td>
                    <td>011 731 5290</td>
                    <td>1.52</td>
                    <td>2019-12-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P00015E8W</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000VCZP</td>
                    <td>Temperate A</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>110.34</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>2.40</td>
                    <td>113.98</td>
                    <td>92.34</td>
                    <td>110.78</td>
                    <td>1st Fusion Asset Management</td>
                    <td>011 731 5290</td>
                    <td>1.46</td>
                    <td>2019-12-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P00015E8Y</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000OINH</td>
                    <td>Asset Select FvF A1</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>161.50</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td/>
                    <td>175.92</td>
                    <td>130.59</td>
                    <td>162.74</td>
                    <td>27Four Investment Managers</td>
                    <td>011 442 2464</td>
                    <td>1.64</td>
                    <td>2020-03-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P0000WFJ5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000P8T4</td>
                    <td>Gebalanseerde FvF A1</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>2230.48</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>46.01</td>
                    <td>2385.31</td>
                    <td>1812.42</td>
                    <td>2245.13</td>
                    <td>27Four Investment Managers</td>
                    <td>011 442 2464</td>
                    <td>1.49</td>
                    <td>2020-03-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P0000XPFJ</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F000002RCP</td>
                    <td>ShariahAktieweAandeleA1</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>220.39</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>1.44</td>
                    <td>238.97</td>
                    <td>174.92</td>
                    <td>221.89</td>
                    <td>27Four Investment Managers</td>
                    <td>011 442 2464</td>
                    <td>1.80</td>
                    <td>2020-03-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P0000JYV4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000OINK</td>
                    <td>ShariahGebalanseerdeFvFA1</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>144.89</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td/>
                    <td>156.57</td>
                    <td>128.91</td>
                    <td>145.77</td>
                    <td>27Four Investment Managers</td>
                    <td>011 442 2464</td>
                    <td>1.56</td>
                    <td>2020-03-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P0000WFJ8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <td>F00000P8T6</td>
                    <td>Stabiele FvF A1</td>
                    <td>&lt;</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>1853.78</td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>74.06</td>
                    <td>1924.38</td>
                    <td>1542.18</td>
                    <td>1862.09</td>
                    <td>27Four Investment Managers</td>
                    <td>011 442 2464</td>
                    <td>1.40</td>
                    <td>2020-03-31T00:00:00.000</td>
                    <td>ZAR</td>
                    <td>0P0000XPFL</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </story>
    </text>
</doc>
```

The `<tr[11]>` contains the information required for the header. I would like to group the information by the header with the number listed in `<tr[12]>` and display it only once per group using XSL 1.0. See the progress I've made. The current method creates the header for all content, but I'm thinking some sort of count or if notion would do the trick. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
</xsl:text>
        <doc xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xml:lang="af">
            <story>
                <text>
                    <table>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
                            <tr colspan="3" class="NewSTOXSubheadEffekte">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./td[position()='11']"/>
                                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./td[position()='12']"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="61%" class="NewSTOXEffekeLeft">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./td[position()='2']"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="22%" class="NewSTOXEffekeRight">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./td[position()='10']"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="17%" class="NewSTOXEffekeRight">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./td[position()='6']"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </text>
            </story>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's my attempt at the grouping method as noted. I'm not getting any results and as mentioned. Some pointers would be really awesome.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="by-fundmanager" match="story" use="/td[11]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <doc xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xml:lang="af">
            <story>
                <text>
                    <table>
                        <xsl:for-each select="story[count(. | key('by-fundmanager', td[11])[1]) = 1]">
                            <xsl:sort select="/td[11]"/>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" class="groupheader">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(td[11])/text()"/>
                                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(td[12])/text()"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('by-fundmanager', td[11])">
                                <xsl:sort select="/td[2]"/>
                                <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-fundmanager', concat(string(td[11]),string(td[2])))[position() = 1])">
                                    <xsl:element name="td">
                                        <td class="stocksleft" width="61%">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string(td[2])/text()"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="stocksright" width="22%">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="td[5]/text()"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="stocksright" width="17%">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="td[6]/text()"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </text>
            </story>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1 has been treated here and elsewhere http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html so try to adapt such code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at the grouping instructions and try to adapt the code.

Comment: OK, this grouping method seems logical, but I'm not sure if the option applies to my problem since the structure is tabled in a traditional method without any clear content indicators.

Comment: Try to use `match="tr" use="td[11]"` in the key and then process the `tr` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but it is still resisting me.

Comment: You haven't shown which exact output you want but check whether https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3o gives you the groups you want, if yes, it should be easier to fill in any details data of each group.